# Cannot explode string quirky results

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
     if($heightparts[0]>9){
       echo "height=>".$heightparts[0];
       $pp=explode("",$heightparts[0]);
       var_dump($pp);die();
         //$heightparts=explode("",$heightparts[0]);
     }
```

Here's my output: `height=>52bool(false)`

`$heightparts[0]` has the value of 52 in it currently.

I dont understand why exploding on the number `52` is returning bool false. I even tried casting `$heightparts[0]` as a string.

Comment: Did you try to read a manual? Or anyone else should do it for you?

Comment: There's no need to post any content of anything. There's a need to read a manual and see a string `If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE.`

Comment: You can not `expand()` with `""`. What do you want do achieve?

Comment: @GennadiyLitvinyuk I want to split the string into an array of 5 and 2

Comment: You can treat string as an array. :)  Really. If you want an array like array(5,2) then you can use `$arr = array();for($i=0;$i<strlen($heightparts[0]);$i++){ $arr[]=$heightparts[0][$i] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an `echo` immediately followed by `var_dump`

The `echo` outputs `52` and the `var_dump` outputs `bool(false)`

From the manual entry of [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_split()` for this:

```
if ($heightparts[0] > 9) {
   echo "height=>".$heightparts[0];
   $heightparts = str_split($heightparts[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
if($heightparts[0]>9){
  echo "height=>".$heightparts[0];
  $pp=str_split($heightparts[0]);
  var_dump($pp);die();
}
```

**Output:**

```
height=>52
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

**Explanation:**

According to the manual [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) you can split strings only to return otherwise returns false:

> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE.

You have turned off error reporting, otherwise you would have been produced error:

> Warning: explode(): Empty delimiter in...